# How to properly get the variable name and import it to task schedular with powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have some problem with this line of code. Currently I'm able to loop all the xml files name inside a folder. But the how to use that variable and put after C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\? Currently the powershell always detect it as the text.

```bsh
$fileDirectory = "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\*.xml";
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory)
{
    $file.name
Register-ScheduledTask -xml (Get-Content "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\$file.name" | Out-String) -TaskName $file.name -TaskPath "\Job" -User "MyAccount" –Force
}
```

Comment: Either do `"C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\$($file.Name)"` OR `(Join-Path -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job' -ChildPath $file.Name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround your `$file.name` in `"C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\$file.name"` with the [Subexpression Operator `$()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#subexpression-operator--), otherwise it's just trying to substitute the `$file` part.

Compare this:

```bsh
PS> $file = get-item "c:\temp\temp.txt"
PS> "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\$file.name"
C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\C:\temp\temp.txt.name
```

with this:

```bsh
PS> $file = get-item "c:\temp\temp.txt"
PS> "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\$($file.name)"
C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\temp.txt
```

The first example evaluates `$file` (which is a [System.IO.FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) object) to `C:\temp\temp.txt` and just replaces `$file` in the string, leaving a trailing `.name` as literal text.

The second example evaluates `$($file.name)` to `temp.txt` (which is a string) instead and replaces the entire `$($file.name)` subexpression.

But simpler still, in your case you could just use `$file.FullName` which gives the full path:

```bsh
PS> $file = get-item "c:\temp\temp.txt"
PS> $file.FullName
c:\temp\temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the f-format operator.

```
$fileDirectory = "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\*.xml";
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory)
{
    $file.name
Register-ScheduledTask -xml (Get-Content "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Job\{0}" -f $file.name | Out-String) -TaskName $file.name -TaskPath "\Job" -User "MyAccount" –Force
}
```